# ActiveRecord query group and Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This problem appeared when I changed Sqlite3 to PostgreSQL.
Seems like I cannot use [group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) method when I use postgres.

```
> Post.group(:user_id).all

Post Load (74.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" GROUP BY user_id
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  GROUP BY user_id
```

Is it possible to use equivalent query to avoid hardcoded SQL and use benefit of elegant AR methods?